# Git & Deployment: Local changes staged, committed, and pushed, not showing on remote

Tags: git, deployment, version-control, repository

I know this seems common, but I've Googled around and searched SO for this, but most responses I've seen only seem to tell me to do what I've already done...

1. Made changes
2. Staged files
3. Committed changes locally
4. Pushed to remote origin/master

The transcript keeps saying "Everything up-to-date", but none of the committed changes show up in the remote branch. (SSH'ing and viewing the directory shows only the .git folder and none of the pushed changes.)

The remote was an empty repo set to bare (`# git config --bool core.bare true`).

The master branch is checked out locally.

#### UPDATE

In light of discussion below, I thought it prudent to clarify the original intent...

The remote is intended to be a live site, thus a bare repo would not be desired and a working tree would be necessary on the remote, but still facilitating the ability to "push" updates would still be desirable.

See also my answer below for this particular case...

Comment: How did you check is it empty? What command?
Where is local and where is remote?

Comment: Updated answer to answer this and add other details.

Comment: The remote repo was empty as it had just been initialized

Comment: Local is on my machine. Remote is on server.

Comment: brb will try to reproduce

Comment: Much appreciated, Marcin

Comment: ok, and why did you use git config --bool core.bare true? i always use git init --bare, my repo structure has no .git folder, but all the stuff thats inside.

Comment: Git is a source control tool, not a deployment tool. As well as source control you will want a strategy for deploying your code into production. This will likely involve pulling a known version of the code (perhaps referenced by a tag) _from_ a Git repository.

Comment: Thanks, Charles. Agreed. I actually was amid writing an answer somewhat to this end when I saw your comment.

Answer (score 4):

Pushing to a repo doesn't change that repo's working tree, even if it has one. A bare repo has no working tree, though, and typically you only push to bare repos anyway.

To put it another way, pushing to another repo will *never* change any files associated with that remote except for the files in the .git directory, where all the repo data is stored.

Comment: Right, I knew that the norm was to push to bare repos, so I set the bool config value to true (not sure if that's the best method).

Comment: Okay, so what must I do differently to change the actual files?

Comment: Well, one way to make a working tree reflect some commit is with `git checkout <commit>`.

Comment: I think you're missing the point, which is that `git push` is *not* for moving your local files to another machine somewhere.

Comment: @Ryan Stewart: There is 1 thing i dont get, when i try to execute OP bare repo creation command line, i always get "could not lock config file .git/config: No such file or directory", and that he had .git in remote repo, while in all my bare repos there is no .git dir, all stuff from .git dir is kind of level higher (HEAD/branches/refs)? Why he had this? Any ideas?

Comment: @Marcin: As I read it, OP probably did something like `git init; git config --bool core.bare true`, which would create a non-bare repo, then immediately switch it to bare, meaning you'd have a .git directory and nothing else. You get the structure you're describing if you do a `git init --bare`, i.e. when you create a repo as bare from the start.

Answer (score 2):

I read into this behaviour and discovered it was a deliberate design decision not to update the remote working tree during a "push" operation:

- [Why won't I see changes in the remote repo after "git push"?](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Why_won.27t_I_see_changes_in_the_remote_repo_after_.22git_push.22.3F)

I normally don't use a remote working tree (bare repository) but this feature obviously causes some pain if you're using Git for deployment. Thankfully there is a solution using commit hooks to trigger a tree update. See:

- [Pushing to git remote working copy](http://jennyandlih.com/pushing-remote-git-working-copy)
- [Git Tip: Auto update working tree via post-receive hook](http://debuggable.com/posts/git-tip-auto-update-working-tree-via-post-receive-hook:49551efe-6414-4e86-aec6-544f4834cda3)

Answer (score 1):

I sugest, removed remote repo dir, mkdir new one, execute git init --bare, and try again. Then for check ssh to server, go to repo dir and execute git log, you should see your changes there.

Comment: I will try this. Perhaps my manual setting of core.bare is bad practice instead of setting the --bare option on init?

Comment: Never inited bare repo your way, so hard to tell, by mine works fine all the time :)

Answer (score 0):

*NOTE: This answer is included for the specific case intended in the OP. The other answers are helpful in general cases.*

As @Ryan Stewart rightly pointed out, pushing does not update the working tree (the actual content of the live site in the OP's case) and yet a bare repo has no working tree.

And since a bare repo is needed in order to push to, a detached working tree will be needed for Apache to actually serve up as the live site.

I'm not sure if this is best practice, but to do this, you could essentially...

### Do this on the server (separate from your local clone):

1. Create a repo with a working directory for the live site
2. Create a separate bare repo
3. Make the bare repo a remote of the live repo and push the live master to it
4. Create hooks (scripts) between the main and the bare repos to keep them synced

I'm new to the concept of hooks in Git, so I won't elaborate further, for fear of further foot-feasting, so I refer you to the source:

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks